# Showing $f$ is monotonely decreasing

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

Let $\lambda_1 < \lambda_2 < \lambda_3$ and $a_1, a_2, a_3 > 0$.

$$f(x) = {a_1 \over {x - \lambda_1}} + {a_2 \over {x - \lambda_2}} + {a_3 \over {x - \lambda_3}}$$

Why does this function is monotonely decreasing on $x \in (\lambda_1, \lambda_2)$?

I can see that $\lim_{x\to\lambda_1+} f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\lambda_2-} f(x) = -\infty$, but I'm not sure how to show monotone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $x_{1},x_{2}$ with $x_{2} > x_{1}$ and show that $f(x_{2}) - f(x_{1}) < 0$ by using algebra.

Comment: I just compared each term to it's equivalent and conclude that for $x<y$: $f(x) > f(y)$.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the derivative. It's negative.

Addendum:

The sum of increasing/decreasing functions is increasing/decreasing.

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately I am not allowed to use derivative (It's going to be our next material).

Comment: @AnnieOK: It's going to get ugly if you want to use purely algebraic manipulations, it's certainly possible to solve it that way, but it'll be tedious and ugly. If it's a calculus question then differentiation is the best tool you have in your toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

$$f'(x)=\frac{-a_1}{(x-\lambda_1)^2}-\frac{a_2}{(x-\lambda_2)^2}-\frac{a_3}{(x-\lambda_3)^2}$$
The denominators are strictly positive and as long as $\lambda_3\notin(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$ and thus the function is always negative